# Unable to post image into facebook using SLComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, facebook, image, ios6, slcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to post image into facebook and twitter. I am fine with twitter but not with facebook using SLComposeViewController class. With out add image i am able to post text and url into facebook. The problem is when i use add image i was unable to post this image and also text, url. SLComposeViewController shows image, text and url when i send. I have correct appId and i did not get any errors. But the problem is still there. I don't where the problem is. Please help me.

```
    - (void)performFBRequestUploadForImage{

        [self showListOfFaceBookAccountsFromStore];
                if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
            {
                SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController         composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

                 SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                     NSString *output;
                    switch (result) {
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                            output = @"ACtionCancelled";
                            break;
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                            output = @"Post Successfull";
                            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Face Book Message" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                 };

                [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images4.jpg"]];
                [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"I am developer."];
                [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
                [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
                [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
            }

    }

- (void)showListOfFaceBookAccountsFromStore
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];


    if( [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook] )
    {

        NSDictionary *options = @{
        @"ACFacebookAppIdKey" : myAppId,
        @"ACFacebookPermissionsKey" : @[@"publish_stream"],
        @"ACFacebookAudienceKey" : ACFacebookAudienceFriends};
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if(granted) {
                ACAccount * account = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType] lastObject];
                NSLog(@"Facebook user: %@",[account username]);
                if([account username]==NULL){
                    [self facebookAlert];
                } else {



                }

            }
            else{
                  NSLog(@"Read permission error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        [self facebookAlert];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used below code in my projects to post the image it works fine.

```
    if([SLComposeViewController instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isAvailableForServiceType)] != nil)
    {
        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
        {

            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
                if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                    NSLog(@"Cancelled");

                } else

                {
                    NSLog(@"Done");
                }

                [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
            };
            controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

            [controller setInitialText:@"Check out my Christmas Gift!"];
            [controller addImage:@"gift.jpg"];

            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

        }
```

You just try follow below tutorials

1. [Tutorial 1](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-inbuilt.html)

2.[Tutorial 2](http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/iphone/integrating-facebook-ios/)

Comment: Thank you for replay. I have added your code but i did n't get image. But when i remove addImage: method i have got message in my face book.

Comment: you just check whether the image has stored in facebook album instead of wall

Comment: @PrasadG i added two tutorials just look at it

Comment: Thanks for giving advise. You are right.These photos are in albums.

Comment: This code has not resolved my issue. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881429/unable-to-share-pdf-on-facebook-using-slcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

I checked the internet and noticed a few discussion in the recent 1 or 2 days related to this issue and they seem to related to Facebook bug. So if your code post messages and images successfully to Twitter, then don't worry! you are doing correctly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868518/sharekit-not-sharing-link-to-facebook/

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4805777

Answer (score 0):

```
  I have resolved through open present-view controller in navigation-bar.it may help you.

 SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [controller setInitialText:shareFrom];
    [controller addImage:self.photoImageView.image];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dayCareWebsite]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    });
```