# How to post to my Facebook wall without saving the image to a photo album

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the following method to share an image and a url to the user's Facebook wall. The problem is that because I'm adding an image with the post it ends up being saved in a Facebook photo album. Perhaps this is the default behaviour, although I swear at one point it was posting just to the wall with a photo and not to a photo album.

thanks for any help

```
- (IBAction)shareAction:(id)sender {
    SLComposeViewController * fbController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbController setInitialText:@"App Name"];

     NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:sideSwipeCell];
  //  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // output id of selected deal
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"deal id for selected row is %@", [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]);
#endif
    // display the youdeal deal image
    link = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];

    // download the youdeal deal image for FB posting

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
    NSLog(@"url to image share %@", url);

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(@"data to image share %@", data);

    UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSLog(@"tmpImage to image share %@", tmpImage);

    ydImage = tmpImage;

    NSLog(@"ydimageview.image %@", ydImage);

  //  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAndLoadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    [fbController setInitialText:@"Check out this link."];
    [fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
    [fbController addImage:ydImage];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
#ifdef DEBUG

                NSLog(@"User Cancelled.");
#endif
                [self removeSideSwipeView:YES];
            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
#ifdef DEBUG
                NSLog(@"Posted");
#endif
                [self removeSideSwipeView:YES];

                CustomAlertView *fbAlert = [[CustomAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Name" message:@"Facebook Post Successful!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                [fbAlert show];
            }
                break;
        }};

    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You mean image is saved in the photo library after being uploaded ?

Comment: @RajanBalana yes. I would like it to simply post a link and an image to the the user of the app's wall.

Comment: Please add the code of imagePickerDidFinishPickingMedia method. Thanks

Comment: the image is coming from a URL and I'm not using the imagePickerDidFinishPickingMedia: method

Comment: it might be a FB bug. sometimes they save to the albums sometimes not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868560/unable-to-post-image-into-facebook-using-slcomposeviewcontroller?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it might be an FB bug. sometimes they save to the albums sometimes not [Unable to post image into facebook using SLComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868560/unable-to-post-image-into-facebook-using-slcomposeviewcontroller?rq=1)